# How to add a reverse feature for a bubble sort algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm currently trying to add a reverse feature to a bubble sort algorithm.

This is my current state:

```
_bubble_sort(self, reverse=False):
    lst = list(self.unsorted_tuple)

    swapped = True
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
            if lst[i] > lst[i + 1]:
                lst[i], lst[i + 1] = lst[i + 1], lst[i]
                swapped = True

    return lst
```

I do not know how I could implement the reverse feature reverse = False. Does anyone know how to implement this feature?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```py
if lst[i] > lst[i + 1]:
```

no matter what *reverse* value will be, the operator will always be *greater* (***>***), while in some cases (depensing on *reverse*) you need the *lower* (***<***) one. 
The easiest way of achieving this is replacing the operator with a function that does the comparison, and that function also takes *reverse* into account. Here's an example that uses *lambda*.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
#import operator


def bubble_sort(unsorted, reverse=False):
    compare_func = (lambda x, y: x < y) if reverse else (lambda x, y: x > y)  # Create a separate function depending the value of reverse, so it's not checked every time the function is called
    #compare_func = operator.lt if reverse else operator.gt  # Use operator instead of lambdas
    lst = unsorted[:]  # Create a copy of the list
    swapped = True
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
            if compare_func(lst[i], lst[i + 1]):
                lst[i], lst[i + 1] = lst[i + 1], lst[i]
                swapped = True
    return lst


def main():
    l = [2, 6, 9, 1, 4, 7]
    reverse = False
    print("Reverse: {0:}\n  List: {1:}".format(reverse, bubble_sort(l, reverse=reverse)))
    reverse = True
    print("Reverse: {0:}\n  List: {1:}".format(reverse, bubble_sort(l, reverse=reverse)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Notes**:

- I had to modify your code a bit
- I also incorporated [[Python 3.Docs]: operator - Standard operators as functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) usage (the commented lines) instead of *lambda*s. Many might say that this variant is much clearer

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058256197]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Reverse: False
>   List: [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9]
> Reverse: True
>   List: [9, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1]
>
> Done.
> ```